# two divs side by side occupying entire container area and handling resizing events too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

this is the code for two divs placed side by side such that on minimizing the first div the second should automatically occupy the remaining space. When the first div is brought back to original position, the second should automatically reduce its size.

One more constraint here is that, the sizes of the divs are not fixed by pixels, they are infact had to be mentioned as percentages. Can any one help in this regards?

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
<div class="left"><button class="collapse-expand"></button></div>
 <div class="right">
    <!--<button class="collapse-expand"></button>-->
    </div>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/rams10786/wrv8r91r/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have acomplished what you want by not floating the right div and setting it to always 100%.

```
    .right{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #67b168;
    }
```

Also I commented the size change in the jquery code:

```
    if($('.left').css("width")=='37px'){
         $('.left').animate({width:"20%"});
         // $('.right').animate({width: "80%"});
    }
```

This is the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfpamqb7/1/

Comment: Okay Thanks for the reply. I have one more problem here, I dont want my right div to be beneath the left div. I want the two divs share the parent divs space. in simple terms the right div should take the complete available space left by the "left" div.

Also, A lot of content is going to be put in to those divs in the future. I just tried to put some boxes in to right div. Its going out of the border:

Comment: I don't think I understand. As the code is currently, the `.right` div is always to the right and nothing is overlapping. Do you have examples or more info about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have updated the code to show it. It some how shows the text properly but not the inner div.
Please have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/jfpamqb7/5/

Comment: I have been able to make the `.inner-div` to stick to the container by simply floating it to the left, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j31xt3ap/1/). You can also use `display: inline-block` instead. I find it easier to work with inline-blocks but float is more compatible with older browsers.